# iOS - get a unique ID on app install

Tags: ios, app-store

I'd like to send users to my app page in the App Store with a unique ID. After they install the app and open it for the first time, I'd like the app to send that unique ID to my server so I can provide them with a personalized experience.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, there is no way to link an app installation to a particular referral

Comment: You can use application:openURL:options: and identify URL schema for iTunes

Comment: there is no such marketing resource yet in Apple's repertoire (probably it will not be ever).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot take `IMEI` and phone number of user mobile, Apple is restricted to get these uniqueID's.

You have to store UDID in keychain. for this you have to download keychainwrapper class and store the UDID generated by above code:

```
 UIDevice *device = [[UIDevice alloc]init]; 

   NSString *idForVend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device identifierForVendor]];

   NSLog(@"Identifier For Vendor : %@",idForVend);
```

follow this link it will solve your problem for sure: How to store a string in KeyChain , iOS? , iOS? If you use this If you delete app And install again it will remain same DeviceID.

Comment: that is not an answer to the OP.